# EF Core 2.1.4 NRE for entity when the child data is null

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

We are in process of migrating our project from .net core 1.0 to 2.1. Ever since I migrated the code to 2.1, some of our tests have started failing. One such case is because our entity throws NRE when one of the child properties is null. This happens when we call **DbSet.Include** on the entity like:

```
await this.goalEnvisionDbContext.UserConfirmations.Include(x => x.User).SingleOrDefaultAsync(uc => uc.UserId == userId);
```

See the value for user id in the watch window and the context. But the function call returns null because we have included the call to load child entities. How should I fix the tests?

For reference, we are using in-memory database for testing. Here's how I setup the context for my tests,

```
var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GoalEnvisionDbContext>();
builder.UseInMemoryDatabase("GoalEnvision.UnitTests");
dbContextOptions = builder.Options;
```

We had similar problems for few other tests, but I googled and came across a solution that suggested we should use sync calls and that it will be fixed in 2.1 but I am already running on 2.1.4. Secondly its not always possible to switch async calls with sync calls.

See the workaround [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9038#issuecomment-314571509) and another mention of the problem [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10121)

[image]

Comment: failing to reproduce your issue (no exception is being thrown from my minimal setup so far). Can u give a link to a plunkr or somewhere I can see your Startup class and DbContext configurations